# Equal height matrix brackets in math mode

Tags: math-mode, formatting, matrices

I'm trying to express a complicated mathematical expression involving the summation of two matrices. One matrix contains a summation with a condition ("a=0 or b=1"), which I'm expressing underneath the Sum symbol using the "substack" approach, as suggested in: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Unfortunately, this causes the matrix bracket top and bottoms to misalign, as shown: 
[image]

It would look better if this was not the case.

Can this be fixed please?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Minimum working example:

\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\sum_{i=1}^{a} A & \cdots & B \\
\vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\
B & \cdots & -\sum_{i=1}^{a} A
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{\substack{
        a,b,c,d \\
        a=0~\mathrm{or}~b=1
}} 
A_{ijkl}
-
\sum_{\substack{
        a,b,c,d \\
a=0~\mathrm{or}~b=1
}} 
B_{ijkl} \\
\vdots\\
\sum_{\substack{
        a,b,c,d \\
a=0~\mathrm{or}~b=1
}} 
C_{ijkl}
-
\sum_{\substack{
        a,b,c,d \\
a=0~\mathrm{or}~b=1
}} 
D_{ijkl}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\vphantom` in first `bmatrix` to force a bracket as large as the one used in second `bmatrix`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Minimum working example:

\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\vphantom{\sum_{\substack{
        a,b,c,d \\
        a=0~\mathrm{or}~b=1
}}}%
-\sum_{i=1}^{a} A & \cdots & B \\
\vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\
B & \cdots & -\sum_{i=1}^{a} A
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{\substack{
        a,b,c,d \\
        a=0~\mathrm{or}~b=1
}} 
A_{ijkl}
-
\sum_{\substack{
        a,b,c,d \\
a=0~\mathrm{or}~b=1
}} 
B_{ijkl} \\
\vdots\\
\sum_{\substack{
        a,b,c,d \\
a=0~\mathrm{or}~b=1
}} 
C_{ijkl}
-
\sum_{\substack{
        a,b,c,d \\
a=0~\mathrm{or}~b=1
}} 
D_{ijkl}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here I use TABstacks, in the form of a `\bracketMatrixstack` and `\bracketVectorstack`.  Three additional parameters must be set:

1. `\setstackgap{L}{22pt}` defines the interrow baselineskip of the stacks;
2. `\setstacktabbedgap{1em}` sets the intercolumn gap in the matrix;
3. `\newcommand\mystrut{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{2ex}}` defines a strut that I place just before the end of the stacks, so that the brackets associated with both stacks are the same depth/height.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
Minimum working example:

\begin{equation*}
\setstackgap{L}{22pt}
\setstacktabbedgap{1em}
\newcommand\mystrut{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{2ex}}
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 
\bracketMatrixstack{
-\sum_{i=1}^{a} A & \cdots & B \\
\vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\
B & \cdots & -\sum_{i=1}^{a} A
\mystrut}
+
\bracketVectorstack{
\sum_{\substack{
        a,b,c,d \\
        a=0~\mathrm{or}~b=1
}} 
A_{ijkl}
-
\sum_{\substack{
        a,b,c,d \\
a=0~\mathrm{or}~b=1
}} 
B_{ijkl} \\
\vdots\\\mystrut
\sum_{\substack{
        a,b,c,d \\
a=0~\mathrm{or}~b=1
}} 
C_{ijkl}
-
\sum_{\substack{
        a,b,c,d \\
a=0~\mathrm{or}~b=1
}} 
D_{ijkl}
\mystrut}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]